# Rastrear coordenadas gps de um aparelho e mostrar em outro

Tags: google-maps, mobile, maps

Estou aprendendo a usar o Intel XDK para desenvolver pra mobile. E queria saber como faz pra rastrear a posição de um aparelho e mostrar na tela em outro, assim como o Easy Taxi faz. Alguem pode ajudar nessa?! vlw galera!

Answer (score 1):

Bem, isso é uma questão de arquitetura da aplicação como um todo, portanto vamos imaginar que temos dois aparelhos A e B.

Verificar a posição de um aparelho A está disponível através dos métodos cordova / phonegap:

> navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition ou navigator.geolocation.watchPosition

O primeiro pega a posição atual e o segundo fica monitorando.

Uma vez obtida a geolocalização do aparelho A ele pode enviar esta informação a uma aplicação Web através de um serviço(isso depende da sua arquitetura), enquanto isso o aparelho B fica monitorando este serviço para receber a localização do aparelho A e mostrar na tela em um mapa ou o que preferir.